# Extract line numbers of all docstrings?

Tags: python, docstring

I'm trying to extract the beginning and ending line numbers of all docstrings in a Python module. Is there a sensible way of doing this without regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this is with the [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ast.html) module.  In particular, [`ast.get_docstring`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ast.html#ast.get_docstring) almost does what you want; it returns the content of the docstring rather than the node, but you can use the same algorithm to find the docstring node and its location:

```
root = ast.parse('''
def foo():
    """the foo function"""
    pass
''')
for node in ast.walk(root):
    if isinstance(node, (ast.FunctionDef, ast.ClassDef, ast.Module)):
        if (node.body and isinstance(node.body[0], ast.Expr) and
            isinstance(node.body[0].value, ast.Str)):
            print node.lineno, node.body[0].value.lineno, node.body[0].value.s
```

Although undocumented, the `lineno` property gives the *last* line of a node, so the `lineno` of the parent node will be the first line of the docstring or the line before it. It doesn't look like there's an easy way to tell the difference between a docstring starting on the same line as the `class` or `def` keyword and on the following line, especially when you consider line continuation (`\`) characters.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to do what I want.

Comment: Do you know if there is a consistent way of getting the line number of any node? Basically, I want to know if there is anything else on the same line as a docstring, because this can happen:

`def test():
    '''This is a docstring'''; pass`

Comment: @Hypercube all nodes have a `lineno` property, so in that case the pass statement will have the same `lineno` as the docstring.

Comment: "a function or class are guaranteed to have at least 1 non-docstring node (if just a pass statement)."  This is not always the case eg:   `class Foo: ""` will have have exactly 1 node. Using `node.body[-1].lineno` might be better.

Comment: @astroMonkey good point, thanks. It looks like comparing `node.lineno` and `node.body[0].value.lineno` is the way to go.